# href="tel:" does not work on ionic 3

Tags: javascript, html, css, ionic-framework, ionic3

Href = "tel" is not working on ionic 3 and this is my code

```
<ion-item color="none" href="tel:(51) 9 9222 - 7607">
  <ion-icon name="call" item-left></ion-icon>
  Contato: {{ property.contato1 }}
</ion-item>
```

[image: This is a image example]

Comment: Please do a better job of hiding the contact info or use dummy data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think `href` is available on an `a`, but not an `ion-item` element. So you want either:

```
<a ion-item href="tel:..."><ion-icon>...</ion-icon></a>
```

or

```
<ion-item>
    <a href="tel:..."><ion-icon>...</ion-icon></a>
</ion-item>
```

*(In these examples, replace the `...` with the appropriate content.)*

Answer (score -1):

**call this method from your html**

```
<button ion-button (click)="callNumber(1236547890)">Call Number</button>
```

**and in .ts write this**

```
callNumber(phoneNumber){
    window.open('tel:' + phoneNumber, '_system');
}
```

Must work in ios and android